# How should I do, If i want to set different css for two popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I use two bootstrap popover in my project, and I want to set different css for they. But it can't set different css, How should I do ?

Comment: Use your own stylesheet, and include in under the bootstrap css file. If that does not work, use the `!important` param in your CSS.

Comment: But bootstrap popover is Dynamically generated. I don't know how to do that. I can change one,but another can't change。

Answer (score 1):

You can add different classes for popovers and add css-styles for this classes.
You sholud add classes with JavaScript, when user click on button:

```
$('.first-button').click( function (){
  $(this).next('.popover').addClass('.different-css');
});
```

Comment: @steven Catch the idea?

Comment: But I can't add class, becuse bootstrap popover is Dynamically generated . How should I do?

Comment: Alexander Seredenko  Thank you